# Spark Job Server multithreading and dynamic allocation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I had pretty big expectations from [Spark Job Server](https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver), but found out it critically lack of documentation.

Could you please answer one/all of next questions:

1. *Does Spark Job Server submit jobs through Spark session?*
2. *Is it possible to run few jobs in parallel with Spark Job Server?* [I saw people faced some troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738862/parallelism-in-spark-job-server), I haven't seen solution yet.
3. *Is it possible to run few jobs in parallel with different CPU, cores, executors configs?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Spark jobserver do not support SparkSession yet. We will be working on it.
2. Either you can create multiple contexts or you could run a context to use FAIR scheduler.
3. Use different contexts with different resource config.

Basically job server is just a rest API for creating spark contexts. So you should be able to do what you could do with spark context.

Comment: what did they mean here https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#features by `Separate JVM per SparkContext for isolation (EXPERIMENTAL)`?

Comment: Initially SJS only supported single context as there was a limitation at spark side that one driver JVM can have only one context. In order to solve this problem we introduced a new flag, that will spawn new JVM per context.